# ClickOnce : Setting deployment provider dynamically

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, clickonce

I don't know whether what I am going to ask is possible or not but I have such requirement so asked.

I am having an .NET application. I published the application using ClickOnce and kept all the published file on Apache server. Then I created an webpage on which an download link is there pointing to .application file. This working fine. :)

Now my scenario is, I am having 5 computer labs each lab will have there respective Webserver(Tomcat) on which an JAVA web application is deployed. What I have to do is I have to publish .NET application 5 times with 5 different server URLs. Like say if my First server is `http://lab1srv:8050/Myapp` then in publish URL will be `http://lab1srv:8050/Myapp/application` same for 2..3..4....(This example is just for 5 server what if I have 100+ server?)

I will be surprised if there is something in which I be able to set deployment provider dynamically or any thing else?

Comment: Umm... can't you just redirect everyone to lab1srv?

Comment: @Krumia, No, Because after installation of .NET application I am taking URL from which its get downloaded using `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query` and then that URL is get stored with application. and I cannot use same URL for all the .NET application across labs.

Comment: That's not what I meant. From your question what I get is, you are worried about how can you _deploy_ a clickonce application in multiple servers. I'm just telling you that you can actually deploy it in one server, and have all other server redirect to the original server, if load balancing is not an issue.

Comment: So you want to have different `Installation Folder URL` values for each deployment?

Comment: @Krumia, Now I will explain my actual scenario, I am having 100+ physically dislocated schools each school will have 2-3 labs each so say for eg. 100 schools will have 200-300 servers on which JAVA application is deployed. Now what I want is whatever my JAVA application is deployed is necessary to open in .NET application which is (.NET application is an browser). So if the JAVA application is opened in other browser it will go to an webpage which will have download link for `.application' file which will get downloaded from its respective server only...

Comment: Now where my prob. start is. To make download URL for `.application` file I Have to build .NET application 200-300 times with that server URLS..

Comment: Or is there any other way to do?

Comment: @Herdo, Yes. But I don't want to build .NET application that many times.

Comment: You could use the mage.exe to modify the URL after building it.

Comment: But the problem is whatever 200-300 server they may have different names like some may have `lab1srv1`,`schoolnamelab1srv1` etc so I cant do this, Or say I don't know what will be the server URL

Answer (score 0):

See the article [Deploying ClickOnce Applications For Testing and Production Servers without Resigning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384243.aspx).

> Starting with the .NET Framework 3.5, **you no longer have to specify a `deploymentProvider` in your deployment manifest** in order to deploy a ClickOnce application for both online and offline usage. This supports the scenario where you need to package and sign the deployment yourself, but allow other companies to deploy the application over their networks.

If your .NET version is lower than that, there is always the [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.80).aspx) (or even better, [MageUI.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.80).aspx)).

Now I don't really have hands-on experience with Mage, but it is used to recreate and sign manifests. It will be a matter of creating a good batch file. After that you just have to copy the files to the servers (which can be automated as well), and then just double click the batch file.

Comment: Cant we set deployment provider URL as "../application/app.application" ? :(

Comment: @Amogh You could. But good luck with [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb608591%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): `The path can be local (c:\foldername\publishfolder), relative (publish\), or a fully qualified location (\\servername\foldername or http://servername/foldername). All HTTP/HTTPS locations must be created with US-ASCII characters. Unicode characters are not supported.

If the installation path is set, the customization files must be in that location for users to install the customization. The location should be set only if you know the final deployment location.`